# How to make select same size as largest option in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, primereact

I have a select and a Dropdown from the `primereact` library, arranged as such:

```
<div>
<SelectComponent
/>
</div>
```

Inside SelectComponent:

```
<div>
<Dropdown
/>
</div>
```

The problem is that the Dropdown content renders far away from the container div, and so when I try to set the width of the parent div to `width: min-content`, it doesn't work, because they aren't actually related elements in the DOM.

How should I proceed then? I would preferentially like to do this in CSS only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please use this Code Sandbox to demonstrate your problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-test-forked-bbns8k